# Is it possible to get AccessToken from an API request? (Facebook Developer)

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-graph-api

I've searched a lot and I've read a lot about this thing, but all the solutions were to get the access token by copy it manually.

is there a way to get the access token automatically by an API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. First of all, you have to integrate the facebook login to generate a user access token.

Look here to get started with the [facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview)

The problem with this token is, it expires really fast:

> Default User and Page access tokens are short-lived, expiring in hours, however, you can exchange a short-lived token for a long-lived token.

However you can use this to generate a long lives access token which expires normally in 60 days. Additionally it will get refreshed when the user uses your app within this 60 days.

This is the URL to generate the `Long-Lives Access Token`. You have to enter your `app-id`, `app-secret` and `access-token`. All three can be found inside the app you created on the facebook developer page.

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&          
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={your-access-token}"
```

Offical documentation to generate a [Long-Lives Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing?locale=en_US)

Hint: You can test all commands through your browser. Just replace the placeholders in the url with your data and put them into the URL-bar. Then you will get an JSON-response from the facebook graph API.

Comment: @AzizAlzayed the topic in general is a bit confusing at the beginng but you can test each command with the browser first before implementing it into your real application. This helped me alot.